# Problems Loading a Custom Model in an Integration Test

Tags: magento2, testing, integration-test

I’m working on an integration test that utilizes a custom model and am unable to load the object. Core objects are loading fine.  I can create a quote using my own fixture without issue. As far as I can tell, the `Account` model and resource model are structured properly.

Consider the following (failing) test:

```
 /**
 * @magentoDbIsolation enabled
 * @magentoAppIsolation enabled
 * @magentoDataFixture loadFixture
 */
public function testOrderProvidesDiscountWithPromo(  ) {

    \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getInstance()->loadArea('frontend');

    /** @var  Mageplaza\Affiliate\Model\Account $affiliate */
    $affiliate = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(Mageplaza\Affiliate\Model\Account::class);
    $affiliate->load(1, 'account_id');

    $quote = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::class);
    $quote->load('test_promo', 'reserved_order_id');

    $this->assertEquals(1, $affiliate->getData('account_id'));
}
```

The `affiliate` account is created using the following fixture:

```
\Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getInstance()->loadArea('frontend');

/** @var  Mageplaza\Affiliate\Model\Account $affiliate */
$affiliate = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(Mageplaza\Affiliate\Model\Account::class);

$affiliate->setAccountId(1)
    ->setCustomerId(1)
    ->setCode('mycode')
    ->setGroupId(1)
    ->setBalance(0)
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->setTree(1);

$affiliate->save();
```

The `$quote` object is loading properly but the `$affiliate` one is not.

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong or are there any extra steps that must be taken to ensure that the custom model loads properly as well?

*(I'm using Magento 2.2 for what it’s worth)*

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was setting the `account_id`, which is `idFieldName` in the resource model.

As a result, when saving the object (ref. `AbstractDb.php`), `$this->isObjectNotNew` evaluates to `TRUE` because the `idFieldName` was set and the new object is not saved (Magento attempts to update the object instead):

```
public function save(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
{
    if ($object->isDeleted()) {
        return $this->delete($object);
    }

    $this->beginTransaction();

    try {
            ...

            if ($this->isObjectNotNew($object)) {
                $this->updateObject($object);
            } else {
                $this->saveNewObject($object);
            }

            ...

    return $this;
}
```

#### Solution

In the fixture above -- updated to:

```
$affiliate->setCustomerId(1)
    ->setCode('mycode')
    ->setGroupId(1)
    ->setBalance(0)
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->setTree(1);

$affiliate->save();
```

And Test (now passing) updated to:

```
/** @var  Mageplaza\Affiliate\Model\Account $affiliate */
$affiliate = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(Mageplaza\Affiliate\Model\Account::class);
$affiliate->load('mycode', 'code');

$this->assertNotNull($affiliate->getData('account_id')
```